# Excel VBA: Error 1004 WorkSheetFunction 'Unable to get Vlookup property"

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to write a quick piece of VBA in Excel 2010 to

- Use Vlookup to find a value
- Return the value in the 3rd Column
- Set a given cell to this value

My difficulty is with the formula.

```
Sub Metrics123()
    Dim x As Integer        
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Test", "A7:D9", 3, False)
    Range("A1").Value = x    
End Sub
```

When I run this I hit the `error 1004: 'Unable to get the Vlookup Property of the WorksheetFunction`

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways for you.

**1)** Use `.Formula` property:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""Justin"",A7:D9,3,FALSE)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

where `.Value = .Value` rewrites formula with it's result

**2)** use `Application.VLookup` with `Range("A7:D9")` instead `"A7:D9"`:

```
Dim x
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    x = Application.VLookup("Justin", .Range("A7:D9"), 3, False)
    Range("A1").Value = x
End With
```

Note, that `x` should be `Variant`, because if nothing found, `Application.VLookup` returns `Error 2042`(`#N/A`)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the quick response. First option works fine.